# plt.savefig saves a blank image

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot, savefig

My code is the following:

```
def distplot_stripplot_buy_signal_3(y_train, y_dev, y_test, y, plot_data_stripplot_distplot, performance_metrics_3_test,
                                   performance_metrics_3_plus_day_train):

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize = (18, 18))

    path = 'D:\\DIGITAL_LIBRARY\\Elpis\\cu2003\\Eddie\\2\\'


    n_train = y_train.shape[0]
    n_dev = y_dev.shape[0]
    n_test = y_test.shape[0]

    n_all = n_train + n_dev + n_test

    start_forecasting_horizon = y.iloc[n_all:n_all+1].index.to_series().dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S').iloc[0]
    end_forecasting_horizon = y.iloc[n_all+300:n_all+301].index.to_series().dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S').iloc[0]

    timespan_forecasting_horizon = round((y.iloc[n_all+300:n_all+ 1+300].index.to_series().iloc[0] - \
           y.iloc[n_all:n_all+1].index.to_series().iloc[0]).total_seconds())


    sns.distplot(plot_data_stripplot_distplot.query('y_test == 1').y_test_pred, color = '#0571b0', 
                 label = 'Price rose in the next 3 mnutes', 
                 ax  = axs[0])
    sns.distplot(plot_data_stripplot_distplot.query('y_test == 0').y_test_pred, color = '#e31a1c', 
                 label = 'Price did not increase in the next 3 mnutes', 
                 ax  = axs[0])

    axs[0].axvline(performance_metrics_3_test.query('fbeta==fbeta.max()', engine = 'python').index[-1],\
                        lw = 4, color = 'black', label = 'optimal threshold using buy_signal_3 on the Test set')

    axs[0].axvline(performance_metrics_3_plus_day_train.query('fbeta==fbeta.max()', engine = 'python').index[-1],\
                        lw = 4, color = 'gray', label = 'optimal threshold using buy_signal_3_plus_day on the Train set')


    axs[0].legend()
    axs[0].set_title(f'Distribution of Probability Scores by Class \n \
    What is the probability to Profit in the next3 to 5 minutes -- if you buy now', fontsize = 18)
    axs[0].set_xlabel('Predicted Probability that the Price will rise in the next 3-5 minutes')

    sns.stripplot(x = 'y_test', y = 'y_test_pred', data = plot_data_stripplot_distplot , ax  = axs[1])

    axs[1].axhline(performance_metrics_3_test.query('fbeta==fbeta.max()', engine = 'python').index[-1],\
                        lw = 4, color = 'black', label = 'optimal threshold using buy_signal_3 on the Test set')

    axs[1].axhline(performance_metrics_3_plus_day_train.query('fbeta==fbeta.max()', engine = 'python').index[-1],\
                        lw = 4, color = 'gray', label = 'optimal threshold using buy_signal_3_plus_day on the Train set')

    axs[1].set_title(f'Distribution of Probability Scores by Class \n \
    What is the probability to Profit in the next 3-5 minutes -- if you buy now', fontsize = 18)
    axs[1].set_xlabel('Ground Truth Outcome \n 0 = The Price did not rise,  1 = Price rose')
    axs[1].set_ylabel('Predicted Probability of a Price \n rise in the next 3-5 minutes')

    axs[1].legend()

    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace = 0.8)

    plt.tight_layout()

    contract = y_train.name[1]

    number_of_rows_train = y_train.shape[0]

    day = y_train.index.to_series().dt.day.iloc[0]



    start_time = performance_metrics_3_plus_day_test.start_time.iloc[0]

    end_time = performance_metrics_3_plus_day_test.end_time.iloc[0]

    duration = performance_metrics_3_plus_day_test.duration.iloc[0] 

    contract = y_train.name[1]

    plt.suptitle(f'Distplot and Stripplot of Probabilities by Class --Ground Truth: buy_signal_3 \n  \
    contract : {contract} -- day : {day} \n \
    forecasting horizon :  from: {start_forecasting_horizon} - to : {end_forecasting_horizon} -- \
    timespan of forecasting horizon in seconds :{timespan_forecasting_horizon} \n \
            Number of timestamps in Train Set: {number_of_rows_train}, Time Span of Test Set : {duration} \n \
            Start Time of Test Set: {start_time}, End Time of Test Set: {end_time}', fontsize = 20, y = 1.1)

    plt.savefig(\
        f'{path}Distplot and Stripplot of Probabilities by Class --Ground Truth: buy_signal_3\
        -contract_{contract}_number_of_timesteps_in_train_set{number_of_rows_train}.pdf')



    plt.show()
```

Then calling the function plots this picture inside the Jupyter Notebook:

```
  distplot_stripplot_buy_signal_3(y_train, y_dev, y_test, y, plot_data_stripplot_distplot, performance_metrics_3_test,performance_metrics_3_plus_day_train)

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

But the file saved is blank:

[image]

Why does this occur and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want to fix your problem input this in your code. I don't know exactly why it happens but it is fixed by this plt.show() should come before plt.savefig()

Explanation: plt.show() clears the whole thing, so anything afterwards will happen on a new empty figure.

```
fig1 = plt.gcf()
plt.show()
plt.draw()
fig1.savefig(y_train, y_dev, y_test, y, plot_data_stripplot_distplot, dpi=100)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not solve the problem.  As you may observe in the original code the plt.show() is placed after the plt.savefig()

Comment: It does work because once because plt.show() removes everything and then you add the plt.draw() then the fig1.savefig is placed so it works.